# Single sign on security of Securekey Concierge

Tags: security

After checking FAQs of Securekey Concierge( company which provides authentication services) I have a doubt that there is a possibility of session replay which can compromise the login security. Here is how it works
Lets say that A is the government site to which I want to log in. Instead of creating a new user name and password for site A, I select Securekey Concierge (Say it site is B). Then from site B I pick my financial instituition where i will be logged in. Lets say it is C. So After log in C I will be redirected to the site A along with a randomly generated token where I will fill the rest of the detail to complete the first time sign in process. So the next time I sign in to site C, the same random token will be sent to site A which will recognise me and won't ask the fill in the same detail I did first time. 
So my question is that I am not sure if the random token flows through site B. If it does then there is a possibility that some one on site B can use that token to impersonate me.
I known single sign on e.g. Google sign in where only two sites are involved and each time the sign is completed that first site get the info from Google session which is always different for each sign in.
But in Securekey Concierge, the same token is sent by the site C each time I log in and if this token flows through the site B which is broker site then I doubt that there could be a session replay using that token. 
If any body aware of Securekey Concierge, could you please elaborate it.

Thanks

Comment: They probably use a challenge response scheme to ensure that each token is bound to the requesting site.

Comment: Maybe, but i have to trust the middle man (site B) the way I trust A and C

Comment: No, you don't.  It would be impossible to generate a token for a site without that site's secret (server-side) key.  Learn about how OAuth works.

Comment: I read Securekey Concierge documentation and it says that it logs the unique token which bank provides each time user logs into the bank. This is the problem as bank is sending unique token to site B and it anonymizes it and logs and redirects back to site A. The real problem is the unique token which remains same each time user logs in to the bank. There is no need a person to log in to the bank to get that unique token. This is the only technical info i was able to find. There may be something more involved. That is why i said that I have to trust B also.

Comment: That token should be a nonce that cannot be reused.  If it is reusable, they have a serious security hole, which you should report to them privately.

Comment: It is the user's unique ID which is sent to site A after getting it from C and going through B. This ID is secret and bank sends it back to B. The site B's only purpose is to create invisibility between A and C. B knows user ID. So is it impossible for someone in B site to find userid and sends to A to gain access. It is not hashed like password. I don't understand what is the sole purpose of site B

Comment: The doc says why user has to trust site B also http://securekey.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SK-UN117-Trust-Framework-SecureKey-Concierge-Canada.pdf

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: It is not end to end security between A and C. B creates new request and response and sees the user id and wraps it to create new id and sends it back to A. B has all the visibility and must be trusted. it does not have to get the id from bank after login . it already knows it. see the technical diagram and step 2 and 3 can be bypassed. step 3 just returns user id which is unique and never changes for a user.

Comment: IDs from different RPs will not match.  B cannot do that.

Comment: I am not talking about IDs from different RPs. Take any ID and using that ID the connection can be made to site A from site B without delegating the request to C and getting response from C. There is no need of C. Since B is just like a proxy and A will never know that the actual user id is retrieved from C or not. The ID is stored both at C and B. There is no conversations between A and C and A has to trust B that user id is really coming from C. So as a user, I have to trust all the three parties. It is same thing like using a proxy server where you trust proxy server for any response.

Comment: Ah; I misunderstood you (I thought B was a third party site).  Yes; if you don't trust an identity provider, you should not use it.

Comment: B is a third party site but it has partnered with A and C to act as credential provider. This means A does not have to talk to C directly. This means I have to trust B to the same extent as I trust A and C. Right?

Comment: Yes.  You also need to trust every other service or dependency used by either party.

Comment: Thanks for the input.